# How to Extract XML Data data using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I can get all the data's except lat,lng and address.

How to get these data's , where i am going wrong?

Here is my code

```
<device_lastupdate>
<version>1.0</version>
<device>
    <id>012980000234020</id>
    <updated_at type="dateTime">2015-01-28T10:21:50+05:30</updated_at>
    <location>
        <lat type="float">12.828383</lat>
        <lng type="float">79.695983</lng>
        <address>Karukinil Amarthanval Street</address>
    </location>
    <odometer type="float">12341</odometer>
    <speed type="float">0</speed>
    <ignition>false</ignition>
</device>
```

and here is my php code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
echo "<h2>".$xml->getName()."</h2><br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $device)
{
    echo "ID : ".$device->id."<br />";
    echo "Updated At : ".$device->updated_at." <br />";
    echo "Latitude : ".$device->lat." <br />";
    echo "Longitude : ".$device->lng." <br />";
    echo "Address : ".$device->address." <br />";

    echo "Odometer : ".$device->odometer." <br />";
    echo "Speed: ".$device->speed." <br />";
    echo "Ignition:".$device->ignition."<br />";
    echo "<hr/>";
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you could break that XML one-liner into a more readable form?

Comment: I am able to get data for lat, lang and address data , what else you want here. The above mention is correct.

Comment: @zan ,these 3 are my problem , how to get those data anyway?can you please post your code?

Comment: @zan , sorry previously i had missed one tag in XML Code , please check  now once again and help to solve :-)

Comment: You have added only one node in xml. Can you add your parent node & multiple child in given xml. Ex:.<parent><child></child><child></child></parent>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make use of this small function that takes object and attribute  and get its value.

```
<?php
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
        echo "<h2>".$xml->getName()."</h2><br />";

        function xml_attribute($object, $attribute)
        {
            if(isset($object[$attribute]))
                return (string) $object[$attribute];
        }

        foreach($xml->children() as $device)
        {
            var_dump($device->location);
            $lng =  xml_attribute($device->location->lng, 0);
            $lat =  xml_attribute($device->location->lat, 0);
            $address =  xml_attribute($device->location->address, 0);
            echo "BOOK : ".$device->id."<br />";
            echo "Author : ".$device->updated_at." <br />";
            echo "Title : ".$lng." <br />";
            echo "Genre : ".$lat." <br />";
            echo "Price : ".$address." <br />";

            echo "Publish Date : ".$device->odometer." <br />";
            echo "Description : ".$device->speed." <br />";
            echo "Ignition:".$device->ignition."<br />";
            echo "<hr/>";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Zan :-) , you are a genius :-) , it's absolutely fine now :-) Many thanks :-)